# PHP - Problema con Array()

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$patron = '/{usuario}/photos/{photo_id}/comments/{comment_id}';

$array_patron = str_split($patron);
$array3 = array();
$variable_open = false;
$ind = -1;
foreach($array_patron as $i => $val){
    if($val === '{'){
        $variable_open = true;
        $ind++;
        continue;
    }else if($val === '}'){
        $variable_open = false;
        continue;
    }else if($variable_open){
        $array3[$ind] .= $val;  // Line number 22
    }
}
print_r($array3);
```

No entiendo por qué da como resultado **NOTICE**s

> NOTICE Undefined offset: 0 on line number 22
>
> NOTICE Undefined offset: 1 on line number 22
>
> NOTICE Undefined offset: 2 on line number 22

A pesar que me muestra éstas **NOTICE**s, el **Array()** resultante es **CORRECTO**.

```
Array (
    [0] => usuario
    [1] => photo_id
    [2] => comment_id
)
```

Alguno puede por favor, explicarme qué sucede?

Comment: y cual es la linea 22?

Comment: @Sergio1871, editado.

Comment: Lo primero que habría recomendado ante tu problema habría sido una revisión de la **[sintaxis de `elseif`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php)**

Comment: @A.Cedano. Excuse me, pero eso no tiene nada que ver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución :)

Descartando las soluciones de @Ivan & @Marcos porque no hacen lo que estoy esperando.

> La solución de Iván porque es manual, y no me permite encontrar más de
> 3 items entre {}.
>
> Y la solución de Marcos porque necesito la concatenación
> obligatoriamente. De otro modo solo resultaría un *Array()* cuyos
> ítems tendrían como valor la última letra de cada una de los
> caracteres entre {}

Mi solución es la siguiente:

**El array debe inicializar su índice para que éste sea válido ante PHP.**
Entonces mi codigo pretendía concatenar a un índice inexistente.
Entonces el código correcto es:

```
$patron = '/{usuario}/photos/{photo_id}/comments/{comment_id}/{sub}/data-long/{code_pek}';

$array_patron = str_split($patron);
$array3 = array();
$variable_open = false;
$ind = -1;
foreach($array_patron as $i => $val){
    if($val === '{'){
        $variable_open = true;
        $ind++;
        $array3[$ind] = ''; // Aquí está la solución
        continue;
    }else if($val === '}'){
        $variable_open = false;
        continue;
    }else if($variable_open){
        $array3[$ind] .= $val;
    }
}
print_r($array3);
```

Al estar el índice inicializado, puede prestarse a concatenaciones sin errores ni *notice*s.

Da como resultado:

```
Array (
    [0] => usuario
    [1] => photo_id
    [2] => comment_id
    [3] => sub
    [4] => code_pek
)
```

Y es flexible para agregar más items entre {} en la variable **$array_patron**

Espero pueda servirles también a ustedes.

Answer (score 2):

### Codigo

```
<?php
$patron = '/{usuario}/photos/{photo_id}/comments/{comment_id}';

$array_patron = str_split($patron);
$array3 = array("","","");
$variable_open = false;
$ind = -1;

foreach($array_patron as $i => $val){

    if($val === '{'){
        $variable_open = true;
        $ind++;
        continue;
    }else if($val === '}'){
        $variable_open = false;
        continue;

    }else if($variable_open){
        $array3[$ind] .= $val;  // Line number 22
    }

}
print_r($array3);
?>
```

---

### Explicacion

La advertencia que te esta arrojando ocurre cuando se ejecuta esta linea:

```
$array3[$ind] .= $val;
```

Lo que estas haciendo, es indicandole algo como:

> Concatena al **valor actual** de `$array3[$ind]` el valor de la variable `$val`.

Lo que ocurre es que en la primera iteracion *(cuando `$ind` vale 0,1,2)* , por cada uno de los indices (0,1,2) `$array3[$ind]` no contiene nada.

Por lo tanto, al ser un indice vacio en la primera iteracion, te arrojara el error **Undefined offset**. Ya que no hay valor con quien concatenarse. Obviamente **esto solo ocurre en la primera iteracion** por cada indice, y es por ello que solo sale 3 veces.

---

### Solucion

Puedes cambiar el valor de `$array3` por este.

```
$array3 = array("","","");
```

En ese caso, dejas cada uno de los indices con un valor inicial, dejando en cierto modo "inicializados" cada uno de sus indices (0,1,2), para cuando hagas la concatenacion con el operador `.=` este tendra de que valor agregarse en la concatenacion.

---

### [Ejemplo en linea!](https://tio.run/##fZH/asMgEMf/9ymOEkhKt8naPzPbF9gbjBFsaoiQqJxmMILPnl1S17UEJoL3Qz/fu9O1bpreTq51LHMyoDUgIOfj4AeJ2kbuWhus5@NyVvoSeW37XplAsWTN0bxkLJOI8ru6YXzAyrtOhyKht2W6c6DsYhSbzdOy59QXKcpzpyrr1Py@kZ1XFNfmQt7zK0k0FpWs2@JRSnrINIgjEKLbjowBLd0UswtCUENjTmFIayUUcCCdW5r0drs/v7YmaPN7Iyoq6hEe/4WnLta0Fe7u3T3wOrGPuaxPeBFLkyUA5/CujQIz9GeFsN9feYxF5lDTr2Ca0oFmezpO0w8)

Comment: @Marcos Hecho, estaba haciendo un ejemplo en tio.run, gracias por el aporte